# what are scenario where re-transmission packets can been seen in wireshark logs

Tags: networking, wireshark

While troubleshooting i came across this challenge ,able to see retransmission packets continuously in packet capture . please let me know in what scenarios this retransmission packets are seen.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally retransmission packet are seen when upstream connected device reject or drops packet .

When source is initiated traffic towards destination as we know TCP protocol is reliable protocal  until aknowledgement is received from destination souce will frequently continuously  sends packets towards destination and when this packet is droped in transit before reaching  destination then in this scenario retransmission packets are seen.